# Why does this code create a valid certificate instead of producing an error?

Tags: php, security, encryption, cryptography, openssl

I have the following (I think) valid code, and this works as expected (tried on Debian stable):

```
$config = array(
    'private_key_bits' => 4096,
    'digest_alg' => 'sha2',
    'private_key_type' => OPENSSL_KEYTYPE_RSA,
);

// Create the private and public key
$res = openssl_pkey_new($config);
if ($res === false) {
    throw new Exception('Key generation failed: '.openssl_error_string());
}

// Extract the private key from $res to $priv
openssl_pkey_export($res, $priv);

echo $priv;
```

This is the result of the above code:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However I noticed that if I change all of the parameters in `$config` to **invalid** ones, I still get a certificate being made instead of some sort of error, and I can encrypt and decrypt, sign and verify with this certificate with no problems:

```
$config = array(
    'private_key_bits' => (-1 * pi()), // negative pi. Also tried with a string
    'digest_alg' => 'blah1024',
    'private_key_type' => 'hello',
);
```

This is an example of what is produced using the above (invalid) parameters:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

So I have a few questions,

1. Is this a bug in PHP? Couldn't this lead to a false sense of security if someone, for example, thought they were creating a really high number of bits only to realize that they misspelled `4096` as `4O96` (with a capital 'o') and it defaulted to 1024 bits, or if it used something like md5 instead of really awesome digest method because they misspelled its name? Or is this somehow by design?
2. What options does PHP use if invalid ones are provided with this function?
3. Is there any way to **verify** the parameters that were used in `$options` to make sure that nothing got messed up along the way like this? **Edit** I see that for the number of bits and the key type are in `openssl_pkey_get_details()`, but not the digest algorithm.

Comment: Sounds like solid PHP code practice to me :(

Comment: PHP functions like to hide problems particularly in the encryption realm. For example: oh your symmetric key is too short, let me expand it for you without telling you.

Comment: @ArtjomB. I think they fixed that in the latest version of the `mcrypt` wrapper, but yes, that shows the general idea of PHP. You can argue about weak typing etc., but you cannot have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @ArtjomB. - OpenSSL CLI does that too. Case in point: `openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -e -in in.txt -out out.txt -nosalt -K AA -iv AA -p` outputs `key=AA000000000000000000000000000000` and `iv =AA000000000000000000000000000000`. ie. it's null padding the keys.

Comment: @Mike - `digest_alg` doesn't do anything in the context RSA key generation.

Comment: @neubert Oh, goodness, that openssl is padding keys and IV's with zeros is information I really *didn't* want to know.